# How to display linux printk() messages in virtual console (tty1)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm trying to solve problem with linux **printk()** messages (Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #87 PREEMPT Fri Feb 7 00:17:11 CET 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux).
What I have is a kernel module which implements **unlocked_ioctl** function from **struct file_operations**. When I call this function from user space with specified **cmd=CMD_PRINTK**, the following code is executed:

```
   case CMD_PRINTK:
   {
         printk(KERN_EMERG    "TEST KERN_EMERG\n");
         printk(KERN_ALERT    "TEST KERN_ALERT\n");
         printk(KERN_CRIT     "TEST KERN_CRIT\n");
         printk(KERN_ERR      "TEST KERN_ERR\n");
         printk(KERN_WARNING  "TEST KERN_WARNING\n");
         printk(KERN_NOTICE   "TEST KERN_NOTICE\n");
         printk(KERN_INFO     "TEST KERN_INFO\n");
         printk(KERN_DEBUG    "TEST KERN_DEBUG\n");
   }
```

What I was expecting is that amount of displayed messages will depend on second value of

```
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/raspberrypi/linux/linux/mod# *cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk*
7   **4**   1   7
```

But what I observe is only the first message "TEST KERN_EMERG\n" which is printed by syslogd btw on every virtual terminal (pts/1...)

In kernel command line I've specified the console as **tty1**

```
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/raspberrypi/linux/linux/mod# *cat /proc/cmdline*

dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708.boardrev=0x3 bcm2708.serial=0xf8900c76 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:90:0C:76 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 **console=/dev/tty1** root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.102:/home/borys/rpi_rootfs ip=192.168.1.103:192.168.1.102:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off rootfstype=nfs
```

I tried to use ***minicom*** to connect to **/dev/tty1** but still I cannot observe any messages displayed there.
I tried to kill ***syslogd*** but it didn't help.

At the moment I think that I don't understand something about virtual terminals. I had setup with STLinux platform and console specified as serial port (**/dev/ttyAS0**) and I was able to connect with serial cable from my host computer and I saw all **printk()** messages.

Can someone explain how to display kernel **printk()** messages in virtual terminal via ***minicom*** connection?
Is it possible at all?
Will it be possible to control **printk()** messages verbosity then?

**Updated: 05.05.2014**

My colleague found first mistake in my cmdline. It should be

```
**console=tty1**
```

not

```
**console=/dev/tty1**
```

because filesystem is not available at the moment of cmdline parsing. After this change I can see debugs in virtual terminal and using 
**dmesg -n x**
as suggested by **oakad** below, I can change its verbosity.

This is almost but not certainly what I wanted actually. The one thing which I'm still missing is the connection to vitural terminal **tty1** via **minicom**.

Currenlty I can see kernel logs only on the screen connected to my raspberry pi or via serial interface **ttyAMA0**.

Additionally when I run my test on PC I can see kernel debugs if I switch to virtual console via *Alt+Ctrl+n* where *n* is the number of virtual console.

What I would like to have is for example:
**ssh** session to raspbery pi in which I start **minicom** and specify **tty1** as a port. 
The same in case of PC I would like to start xterm (**/dev/pts/n**) in which I start minicom and specify **tty1** as a port.

Unfortunatelly both, in case of rasberry Pi and in case of PC I cannot see kernel debugs in such **minicom** session. In case of raspberry Pi I tried to send file from minicom and I saw it was working - file content was displayed in display connected directly to rasberry pi. Unfortuanatelly logs from rasberry to **minicom** are not transferred or are stucked somewhere. Does anyone could tell me if such method for kernel logs display is possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your console "verbosity" level with `dmesg -n x`, where x is the name of the "minimal" message priority you want printed out to the console. Try saying `dmesg -n debug` to see everything on the console, `KERN_DEBUG` messages included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves part of my issues (please check update from 05.05.2014). I will vote up if my reputation will be better than 15 :-).

Comment: Consider adding an appropriate `console` or (`netconsole` if it suits you) to a kernel command line: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial-console.txt (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt)